# Kubernetes - delete all jobs in bulk

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I can delete all jobs inside a custer running

```
kubectl delete jobs --all
```

However, jobs are deleted one after another which is pretty slow (for ~200 jobs I had the time to write this question and it was not even done).

Is there a faster approach ?

Comment: You would have to query the api, create a list from that query, and run all your commands as background job. That should be faster (however you will not know until tested)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I have a script for deleting which was quite faster in deleting:

```
$ cat deljobs.sh 
set -x

for j in $(kubectl get jobs -o custom-columns=:.metadata.name)
do
    kubectl delete jobs $j &
done
```

And for creating 200 jobs used following script with the command `for i in {1..200}; do ./jobs.sh; done`

```
$ cat jobs.sh 
kubectl run memhog-$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-z0-9' | fold -w 8 | head -n 1)  --restart=OnFailure --record --image=derekwaynecarr/memhog --command -- memhog -r100 20m
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try this asap

Comment: you can do `kubectl -n <namespace name> delete ...`

Comment: and with `&` and >16k jobs it will kill your computer

Comment: I remove the `&` if there are too many jobs to remove, it's slower but safer indeed. But otherwise this does the job

Answer (score 61):

It's a little easier to setup an alias for this bash command:

```
kubectl delete jobs `kubectl get jobs -o custom-columns=:.metadata.name`
```

Comment: Expanding this answer: To set up an alias add this line to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` file: `alias delete_all='kubectl delete jobs \`kubectl get jobs -o custom-columns=:.metadata.name\`'`

Comment: Please use this notation 
`kubectl delete jobs $(kubectl get jobs -o custom-columns=:.metadata.name)`
as backticks have several issues:
1. It has a series of undefined behaviors related to quoting in POSIX.
2. It imposes a custom escaping mode with surprising results.
3. It's exceptionally hard to nest.

I recommend [www.shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Answer (score 14):

If you are using `CronJob` and those are piling up quickly, you can let kubernetes delete them automatically by configuring job history limit described in [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#jobs-history-limits). That is valid starting from version 1.6.

```
...
  spec:
    ...
    successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
    failedJobsHistoryLimit: 3
```

Comment: Thanks! I was "playing" with cronjobs and had piled up 17K+.  Deleting all of this is a pain. Lesson learned:)

Comment: Note that the limits have somewhat reasonable defaults of 3 successful and 1 failed jobs.

Answer (score 12):

There is an easier way to do it:

**To delete successful jobs:**

`kubectl delete jobs --field-selector status.successful=1`

**To delete failed or long-running jobs:**

`kubectl delete jobs --field-selector status.successful=0`

Answer (score 6):

This works really well for me:

`kubectl delete jobs $(kubectl get jobs -o custom-columns=:.metadata.name)`

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: @Cizer  I want to get the list of job names that match with the grep statement. ```kubectl get jobs | grep abc-xyt``` gives the output along with status, and time. I used ```kubectl get jobs --output=jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}' | egrep  abc-xyt``` where it fails miserabily to grep the job names which matches with abc-xyt. Any idea?

Comment: @rishi Using custom column:

`kubectl get jobs -o custom-columns=Name:.metadata.name,:.status.startTime | grep nginx` 

Would also work for bulk delete:

`kubectl delete jobs $(kubectl get jobs -o custom-columns=:.metadata.name | grep "nginx-old")`

Answer (score 4):

I use this script, it's fast but it can trash CPU (a process per job), you can always adjust the `sleep` parameter:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Deleting all jobs (in parallel - it can trash CPU)"

kubectl get jobs --all-namespaces | sed '1d' | awk '{ print $2, "--namespace", $1 }' | while read line; do
  echo "Running with: ${line}"
  kubectl delete jobs ${line} &
  sleep 0.05
done
```

Answer (score 4):

The best way for me is (for completed jobs older than a day):

`kubectl get jobs | grep 1/1 | gawk 'match($0, / ([0-9]*)h/, ary) { if(ary[1]>24) print $1}' | parallel -r --bar -P 32 kubectl delete jobs`

`grep 1/1` for completed jobs

`gawk 'match($0, / ([0-9]*)h/, ary) { if(ary[1]>24) print $1}'` for jobs older than a day

`-P` number of parallel processes

It is faster than `kubectl delete jobs --all`, has a progress bar and you can use it when some jobs are still running.

Answer (score 2):

`kubectl delete jobs --all --cascade=false` is fast, but won't delete associated resources, such as Pods

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/8598

Answer (score 1):

Parallelize using GNU parallel

```
parallel --jobs=5 "echo {}; kubectl delete jobs {} -n core-services;" ::: $(kubectl get job -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.status.succeeded==1)].metadata.name}'  -n core-services)
```

Answer (score 1):

kubectl get jobs -o custom-columns=:.metadata.name | grep specific* | xargs kubectl delete jobs

kubectl get jobs -o custom-columns=:.metadata.name gives you list of jobs name | then you can grep specific that you need with regexp | then xargs use output to delete one by one from the list.

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, there's no other way to delete all job at once,because even `kubectl delete jobs` also queries one job at a time, what  Norbert van Nobelen suggesting might get faster result, but it will make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

Kubectl bulk (bulk-action on krew) plugin may be useful for you, it gives you bulk operations on selected resources.
This is the command for deleting jobs 
'  kubectl bulk jobs delete '

You could check details in
https://github.com/emreodabas/kubectl-plugins/blob/master/README.md#kubectl-bulk-aka-bulk-action